# How to select a value from drop down menu in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to click on "Demonstrativo de Caixa" (value='4') with selenium.

Unfortunately I get this error every time:
select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID('ddlRelatorio'))).text
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```
<select name="ddlRelatorio" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ddlRelatorio\',\'\')', 0)" id="ddlRelatorio" style="width:100%;">
<option selected="selected" value="0">Selecione...</option>
<option value="3">Carteira Diária</option>
<option value="4">Demostrativo de Caixa</option>
<option value="5">Posição Diária - Código ISIN Nulos</option>
<option value="6">Fluxo de Caixa</option>
<option value="15">Bloqueio Renda Fixa - Por Corretora/Bolsa</option>
<option value="16">Bloqueio Renda Variável</option>
<option value="17">Extrato - CBLC</option>
<option value="18">Extrato - SELIC</option>
<option value="19">Mapa de Evolução de Cotas</option>
<option value="20">Movimentação Patrimônio Líquido</option>
<option value="21">Movimento de Futuros</option>
<option value="22">Movimento de Renda Variável</option>
<option value="23">Operações Renda Fixa - Simplificado</option>
<option value="24">Posição de Swap</option>
<option value="25">Posição por Cliente - Detalhe</option>
<option value="26">Posição por Cliente</option>
<option value="27">Posição Renda Fixa Detalhado</option>
<option value="28">Posição Renda Fixa Simplificado</option>
<option value="52">Cotas de Patrimônio de Fundos</option>
<option value="54">Posição, Movimentação e Eventos</option>
<option value="55">Rebate de Taxas</option>

</select>
```

This is my code:

```
 Select(driver.find_element(By.ID('ddlRelatorio')))
 select.select_by_visible_text('Demostrativo de Caixa')
 select.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To select the `<option>` with text as **Demostrativo de Caixa** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#ddlRelatorio[name='ddlRelatorio']")))).select_by_visible_text("Demostrativo de Caixa")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='ddlRelatorio' and @name='ddlRelatorio']")))).select_by_visible_text("Demostrativo de Caixa")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
  ```

Comment: How can i click on it?

Comment: @Matheus for [tag:html-select] tags you don't need to explicitly call [_`click()`_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73410537/7429447) method. The `select_by_visible_text()` will do the job.